# How to maintain dental hygiene while bottle feeding?

Tags: infant, newborn, health, feeding, bottle-feeding

https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/8475/2221

> **Dental hygiene:**
>   Drinking from a bottle all day and/or all night can cause tooth decay even in teeth that haven't emerged yet. Both breastmilk and formula have lactose in them which provides food for bacteria in the mouth and allow them to produce cavities.

In my case the baby is 1 month old. I find it difficult to feed her with a spoon single handedly hence restored to bottle feeding.

***She feeds for around 10 minutes every two hours per day.***
What care should be taken to prevent the tooth decay?

Comment: My dentist recommended brushing teeth with a soft cloth before bedtime. At 1 month bedtime, per se, hasn't emerged yet because your child still eats and sleeps around the clock, but it is something to consider. As your child ages you want to move towards brushing gums/teeth with a cloth and then a baby toothbrush at bedtime and giving no forumula, breastmilk, or solid foods after brushing. Your pediatrician can provide good guideance on when night weaning from a bottle is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of tooth decay is not so much regular feedings with the bottle itself, but the habit of the baby going to sleep while eating or drinking something with sugar in it and having that sugary liquid sit in the mouth for hours at a time.

I would think trying to feed a 1 month old with a spoon would be nearly impossible. Spoon feeding starts with solids like baby cereals around 4-6 months of age. Even then, they get more on the bib than in their stomach, so they still get the bulk of their food from bottle and/or breast.

More tips are here:
http://www.webmd.com/oral-health/guide/what-is-baby-bottle-tooth-decay

Comment: As an addendum to this answer, formula, breastmilk, and cow's milk are all sugary liquids though you may not think so. A friend who has chosen to practice all-night nursing while co-sleeping with her toddler was surprised to find that he had developed cavities at 19 months.